# how to put a programmattic menu inside a menubar?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to create a menu programmatically inside a menubar but it is not working.

This code doesn't work:

```html
<p:menubar id="menuBase">
  <p:menu model="#{indicadorManager.indicadoresMenu}" />
  <p:menuitem type="button" action="#{identity.logout}" value="Logout" />
</p:menubar>
```

This one does:

```html
<p:menubar id="menuBase" model="#{indicadorManager.indicadoresMenu}">
</p:menubar>
```

But I want a button to logout the user, first example. Can I do that?

Comment: Add the button dynamically in your `indicadorManager.indicadoresMenu` model.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza work your comments into an answer, so people with the same problem can know.

Comment: @Mindwin you can post the advice from my comment into an answer (feel free to earn free rep)